# Scala: access toLong method of implicit Numeric instance

Tags: scala, traits, numeric, implicit

```
implicit val integralFoo: Integral[Foo] = ???
val myFoo: Foo = ???
val myLong: Long = ???
```

I'm wondering how I can fill in the third line here without explicitly referencing `integralFoo` or using `implicitly`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the necessary implicits.

```
def m[Foo](implicit integralFoo: Integral[Foo]) = {
  import Integral.Implicits._
  val myFoo: Foo = ???
  val myLong: Long = myFoo.toLong()
}
```